# Append a string after a multiple line match in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would need a `sed` or `awk` command to print a line after a multiple line match in bash. For example having this file as input:

```
admin:
  users:
    - user1
    - user2

read_only:
  users:
    - user3

write_only:
  users:
    - user4

access_only:
  users:
    - user5
    - user6
```

..I would need to have this as output:

```
admin:
  users:
    NEW USER
    - user1
    - user2

read_only:
  users:
    - user3

write_only:
  users:
    - user4

access_only:
  users:
    - user5
    - user6
```

The regex should match the first two lines `admin: users:` and then append `NEW USER` line.

How to do this? Should I use sed or awk? How?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide more information with sample inputs and expected output, so that it will be clear for us to help you.

Comment: If you're looking at `sed`/`awk` then why have you shotgun tagged this as `linux`, `perl`, `bash` too?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Updated to be more clear! :)

Comment: @Sobrique because I know this can also be done with awk and perl regex.

Comment: It's the wrong solution to the problem - it's a contextual grammar, and regular expressions don't do that.

Comment: @Sobrique I mean sed/awk/perl command expressions ofc. I just need a sed/awk/per command to do what I described above..

Comment: This does, however, have the smell of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). _Why_ are you trying to insert a blank line into some otherwise perfectly valid and parsable YAML?

Comment: @Sobrique yeah because I posted my question wrong. I don't want a newline inserted there but a new line of code and so another user (I edited the question body). Sorry for this, that's my first question here and I am noob in this lol

Comment: OK. Perl's even better for that then.

Comment: Note - the ones asking to insert 'NEW LINE' are probably all wrong - in order to _remain_ valid YAML, it needs to be `- new username` with the right indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With `sed`

Delimit block between `/^[a-z_]\+:/` and `/^$/`, so you could do somme process in one block:

```
sed -e $'/^admin:/,/^$/{/users:/a\    NewUser\n}'
```

This could be written:

```
NEWUSER="user2017"
sed -e "/^admin:/,/^$/{
    /users:/a\    - $NEWUSER
}"
```

(By using double quotes, I could use variable from commandline or script)

This will render:

```
admin:
  users:
    - user2017
    - user1
    - user2

read_only:
  users:
    - user3

...
```

#### Or **pure** [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)...

```
myadduser () { 
    local crt= line;
    while IFS= read line; do
        echo "$line";
        [ "$line" ] && { 
            [ "${line:0:1}" != " " ] && crt=${line%:} || { 
                [ "${line//*([: ])}" = "users" ] &&
                    [ "$crt" = "${2:-admin}" ] &&
                        printf "    - %s\n" $1
            }
        };
    done
}
```

which could by used:

```
myadduser NewAdminUser <file.txt
admin:
  users:
    - NewAdminUser
    - user1
    - user2

read_only:
  users:
    - user3

...
```

or with optional second argument:

```
myadduser NewWriteUser write_only
admin:
  users:
    - user1
    - user2

read_only:
  users:
    - user3

write_only:
  users:
    - NewWriteUser
    - user4

access_only:
  users:
    - user5
    - user6
```

### But please,

Read [Sobrique's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46178535/1765658)!

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) or [python](/questions/tagged/python) for prototyping like by using [c](/questions/tagged/c) for finalized programmation, you may find apropriate libraries.

Using any of this libraries in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) could be done too.

1st admin user

```
perl -MYAML -E 'undef$/;$s = Load(<>);say@{$s->{admin}->{users}}[0];'
```

Count of admin users

```
perl -MYAML -E 'undef$/;$s = Load(<>);say scalar@{$s->{admin}->{users}};'
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither. It's YAML, so parse it as YAML.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;
use Data::Dumper;

my $stuff = Load ( do { local $/; <DATA> } );

print Dumper $stuff; 

print $stuff->{admin}{users}[0],"\n";

print "List:\n";
print join "\n", @{$stuff->{admin}{users}};

__DATA__
admin:
  users:
    - user1
    - user2
```

Given you've updated your question to 'add a new user to the admin users stanza' my answer has changed - but it still is 'use perl':

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML::Syck;
use Data::Dumper;

$YAML::Syck::SortKeys = 1;

my $stuff = Load ( do { local $/; <DATA> } );

print Dumper $stuff; 

push @{$stuff->{admin}{users}}, "new username";

print Dumper $stuff;

print Dump \$stuff;


__DATA__
admin:
  users:
    - user1
    - user2

read_only:
  users:
    - user3

write_only:
  users:
    - user4

access_only:
  users:
    - user5
    - user6
```

You can one-liner-ify this as:

```
perl -0777 -MYAML -e '$s = Load(<>);unshift @{$s->{admin}{users}}, "new username"; print Dump $s;'
```

This will read from STDIN, do the transform and output valid YAML. `unshift` will insert the username at the start of the array - I'd normally use `push` to insert it at the end.

Note - I used `YAML::Syck` in my previous example because it'd sort the output.

Comment: Yeah, i know it's yaml but I need to parse that file in a bash script.

Comment: You tagged your question `perl` though.

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk for simplicity, clarity, efficiency, robustness, and most other desirable attributes of software.

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' '{$0=gensub(/(admin:\s+users:)(\s+)/,"\\1\\2NEW LINE\\2",1)}1' file
admin:
  users:
    NEW LINE
    - user1
    - user2
```

Comment: I posted the entire yaml file and your awk does not seem to work.. Where am I wrong?

Comment: My best guess is you're not using gawk as my answer states is required. If you use gawk it'll work, if not then it won't.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in Unix (or another environment where the carriage return character isn't used), you can use sed by replacing new lines temporarily:

```
cat file | tr '\n' '\r' | sed "s/admin:\r  users:/admin:\r  users:\r    NEW LINE/g" | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Admittedly hackier than the awk solution above, but adding this for those wondering how to do it easily with sed.

Comment: Thank you! This is working well! Now I have only to understand the syntax of your command lol

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/^admin/{ n=NR+2 }NR==n{ sp=substr($0,1,index($0,"-")-1); 
     printf "%s\n%s\n",sp"NEW USER",$0; next  }1' file
```

The output:

```
admin:
  users:
    NEW USER
    - user1
    - user2

read_only:
  users:
    - user3

write_only:
  users:
    - user4

access_only:
  users:
    - user5
    - user6
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Correct

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/admin:/!b;n;/users:/!b;n;h;s/-.*/- new user/p;g' file
```

If the line does not contain `admin:` bail out. Likewise, if the following line does not contain `users:` bail out. Read and make a copy of the following line, amend the line to contain the `- new user` and then print it and the original.