# Append text line after multiline match and stop on first multiline match

Tags: awk, sed, append, multiline

I would need a sed or awk command, not script, that:

1) matches in file sequentially 2 strings:

```
 # This configuration option has an automatic default value.
 # filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]
```

This is required because any single string can occur in file more than once.
But two of such sequential strings are pretty unique to match them.

2) inserts/appends after matched strings this text line:

```
filter = ["a|sd.*|", "a|drbd.*|", "r|.*|"]
```

3) stops processing after first match and append

So, text file looks like this:

```
     ...

     # filter = [ "a|^/dev/hda8$|", "r|.*/|" ]
     #
     # This configuration option has an automatic default value.
     # filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]

     # Configuration option devices/global_filter.
     # Limit the block devices that are used by LVM system components.
     # Because devices/filter may be overridden from the command line, it is
     # not suitable for system-wide device filtering, e.g. udev and lvmetad.
     # Use global_filter to hide devices from these LVM system components.
     # The syntax is the same as devices/filter. Devices rejected by
     # global_filter are not opened by LVM.
     # This configuration option has an automatic default value.
     # global_filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]

     # Configuration option devices/types.
     # List of additional acceptable block device types.
     # These are of device type names from /proc/devices, followed by the

     ...
```

I would need to have output like this:

```
     ...

     # filter = [ "a|^/dev/hda8$|", "r|.*/|" ]
     #
     # This configuration option has an automatic default value.
     # filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]

     filter = ["a|sd.*|", "a|drbd.*|", "r|.*|"]

     # Configuration option devices/global_filter.
     # Limit the block devices that are used by LVM system components.
     # Because devices/filter may be overridden from the command line, it is
     # not suitable for system-wide device filtering, e.g. udev and lvmetad.
     # Use global_filter to hide devices from these LVM system components.
     # The syntax is the same as devices/filter. Devices rejected by
     # global_filter are not opened by LVM.
     # This configuration option has an automatic default value.
     # global_filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]

     # Configuration option devices/types.
     # List of additional acceptable block device types.
     # These are of device type names from /proc/devices, followed by the

     ...
```

None of found examples on multiline sed examples on stackoverflow is working for me.

I tried F. Hauri example from this topic: [Append a string after a multiple line match in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178395/append-a-string-after-a-multiple-line-match-in-bash)

```
 sed -e $'/^admin:/,/^$/{/users:/a\    NewUser\n}'
```

It works fine, when matching unique words, but did not work for matching sequential text lines like this:

```
 # This configuration option has an automatic default value.
 # filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]
```

and also adding '0, to sed expression to stop on first match did not work in that case.

Updated description to better describe what is the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    awk '
    /^\s+\# This configuration option has an automatic default value\./{
      found=1
    }
    found && !flag && /\s+\# filter = \[ \"a\|\.\*\/\|\" \]/{
      flag=1
      $0=$0 ORS ORS "        filter = [\"a|sd.*|\", \"a|drbd.*|\", \"r|.*|\"]"
    }
    1
    '  test.conf > test.tmp && cp test.conf test.conf.bak && mv -f test.tmp test.conf
```

Comment: I updated your answer to work with leading spaces and added file replacement as well as making backup copy. Thank you very much for proposed solution. I will accept this answer.